# argument pass by reference in obj-c

Tags: objective-c, c

I just did one research, but I am having a problem

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  int r1=40,r2=5;
  swap(r1,r2);

  NSLog(@" temp is %d",r1);
}

void swap(int r1, int r2)
{
  NSLog(@" m i 1st");
  int temp;
  temp=r1;
  r1=r2;
  r2=temp;

  NSLog(@" temp is %d",r1);
}
```

I am getting conflicting type of `swap`; is this correct way of doing this? Thanks!

Comment: i am  sorry , its working fine , just got warning this way is invalid in c99

Comment: i am getting conflicting type of swap ,is this correct way of doing>>??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `r1` and `r2` to be swapped, you either have to pass pointers, or use C++ references. Note that using C++ references will require you to dive into Objective-C++, which in this case means naming your file `.mm` instead of `.m`.

```
void swap_with_pointers(int *r1, int *r2)
{
  int temp;
  temp = *r1;
  *r1 = *r2;
  *r2 = temp;
}

void swap_with_references(int &r1, int &r2)
{
  int temp;
  temp = r1;
  r1 = r2
  r2 = temp;
}
```

Then, use one of your implementations like so:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  int x = 3;
  int y = 4;
  swap_with_pointer(&x, &y); // swap_with_references(x,y);
  printf("x = %d, y = %d", x, y);
  return 0;
}
```

The output, either way:

> x = 4, y = 3

Comment: thanks you are right , but in obj-c i am getting warning as its implicit declaration of swap is invalid in C99

Comment: You just need to declare swap before it is used. Add the line `void swap(int r1, int r2);` at the top of your file.